# Visual Constraints in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

Now I am developing an app, where I use visual constraints.
So question is how to make square subview?

For example: 
I have superview with frame (320 width, 568 height) then I add subview. The frame of this subview should be (320 width, 320 height).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can add a constraint for the view's width to equal it's superview's width and another constraint for the view to have a 1:1 ratio of width to height.

Comment: What if height will be less than width?

Comment: Then you can make view's height to match it's superview's height in the first constraint, can't you?

Comment: @Zhans You can put in both, but at different priorities (obviously the aspect ratio should have the highest priority, and one of the others will break).

Comment: I mean I don't know a size of superview exactly. If the size of superView will be (320, 568) then the size of subview should be (320, 320), If the size of superView will be (320, 240) then the size of subview should be (240, 240)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Sadly, this isn't possible to do visually in IB.</s>  In old versions of Xcode, this was not possible in IB.

However, even in those cases, you can easily add a constraint in code (see [the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html)) to achieve it.

You want something like:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: self 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                            multiplier: 1 
                               constant:0]
```

Comment: I believe it is quite possible to achieve in the IB.

Comment: @F1ank3r My mistake; you're right, it was added recently. I'll edit to clarify.